# if loop to bold certain records and keep others non-bold

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo, while-loop

I'm trying to get returned records from the database. I'm looking to bold returned questions (returned = 1) and non-bold questions (returned = 0) that haven't been returned for this page http://starsQA.com/Qbank

This is the query code so far:

```
<?php
include("db_conn.php");
$qry_string = "select * from stars order by starName ASC";
$prep = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_string);
$prep->execute();
while ($row = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<button class='tosearch spcbtn' id='tglbtn{$row['starID']}'>{$row['starName']}</button>";
    echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
    echo "<div style='color:black;' class='tgldiv' id='tgldiv{$row['starID']}'><b>{$row['starName']}</b><br><ol>";
    $qry_stringq = "select * from questions where starID = ? && approved = 1";
    $prepq = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_stringq);
    $prepq->execute(array($row['starID']));
    while ($rowq = $prepq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<li style='margin:30px'>{$rowq['question']}</li>";
    }
    echo "<ol'></div>";
    echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
 }
?>
```

If you type in *geno segers* into the search box and open his button then questions 1-26 should be bold and question 27 should be non-bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
while ($rowq = $prepq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $bold = $rowq['returned'] == 1 ? ' font-weight:bold;' : '';
    echo "<li style='margin:30px;{$bold}'>{$rowq['question']}</li>";
}
```

Comment: By the way, you should never use inline CSS styles in your HTML layout.